# php create a folder where its name starts with a session

Tags: php

I just want to ask if it's possible to create a folder where the name of the folder will start on a session? I tried this: `mkdir($_SESSION['user_id'] . "/testing/");` and if it is possible, can you help me how? I'm just a newbie. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible, if the webserver has write access to the directory you want to create the dir in. What was the error you got when you tried it?

Comment: Also, when you want to add multiple structured directories at once you have to set the recursive parameter of [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You can use mkdir() function with recursive parameters to achieve the goal:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = 123;

    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        if(!@mkdir($_SESSION['id'] . '/test/', 0777, true)) {
            echo "Dicectory cannot be created";
        };
    }
?>
```

Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.
following is the example.

`ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); // display error if occurs any
 mkdir(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$_SESSION['user_id']."/testing/",0777, true); 
// realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) gives path to you project directory`